# Prove that $(A-B)\cup(B-C) = (A\cup(B-C))-(B\cap C)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

First of all, I've checked with a Venn's diagram, and it can be proved:

$(A-B)\cup(B-C) = (A\cup(B-C))-(B\cap C)$

Then, I wrote the solution in those 2 pictures, but I'm not sure I did it right. If it is possible, can you pinpoint where I failed to use the 'logic statements' correctly? Btw, I've started with RHS, I always prove where it is less sorted, I find it easier to solve that way.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
(A\cup(B-C))-(B\cap C)&=(A-B\cap C)\cup(B-B\cap C)
\\
&=(A-B)\cup(A-C)\cup(B-C)\tag1
\end{align}
Since
\begin{align}
A-C&=(A\cap C^c)\cap(B\cup B^c)
\\
&=((A\cap C^c)\cap B)\cup((A\cap C^c)\cap B^c)
\\
&=(A\cap (C^c\cap B))\cup((A\cap B^c)\cap C^c)
\\
&\subset (C^c\cap B)\cup(A\cap B^c)
\\
&=(B-C)\cup(A-B)
\end{align}
i.e.
$$A-C\subset (B-C)\cup(A-B)$$
So
$$
(A-B)\cup(A-C)\cup(B-C)= (A-B)\cup(B-C)\tag2
$$
Thus by $(1)$ and $(2)$
\begin{align}
(A\cup(B-C))-(B\cap C)&=(A-B)\cup(A-C)\cup(B-C)
\\
&=(A-B)\cup(B-C)
\end{align}

Comment: Reading this, one might have the impression you are turning an inclusion into an equality in the "there is" passage. I think it would be a good idea to write an inclusion there, subsequently adding "but since the reverse inclusion is obvious, we have an equality here". Also, you ought to split the long lines of the equality chains because a mobile from we might not see them all (mine doesn't), and that would leave readers wondering, "WTF is (1)??". I guess the tag (1) is at the end of that `align*`.

Comment: You're welcome. I took the liberty of breaking the long lines myself.

Comment: Perfect! I just had to show the $(A - C) \subset (B - C) \cup (A - B)$. because in my 2nd picture I just "deleted" it. and I can't do that when there is $\cup$ sign. just when there is $\cap$ sign. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Easier, IMHO: if $x$ is in the LHS,

case 1: $x \in A - B$, and then $x \in A$, so $x \in A \cup (B - C)$, and $x \notin B$ so $x \notin B \cap C$. So $x$ is in the RHS.

case 2: $x \in (B - C)$, then also $x \in A \cup (B - C)$. And $x \notin C$, so $x \notin B \cap C$. So $x$ is in the RHS.

This shows one inclusion.

If $x$ is in the RHS, there are two cases again, based on $x \in A \cup (B-C)$.

Suppose $x \in A$. If $x \notin B$, we are done (as then $x$ is in the LHS, as $x \in A - B$). So assume $x \in B$. Then $x \notin C$, as $x \notin B \cap C$, so then $x \in (B - C)$ so $x$ in LHS.

Or assume $x \in (B-C)$. Then we are done right away: $x$ in LHS.

So the other inclusion also holds and we have equality.

We don't always have to write equivalences... That would boil down to purely algebraic (in Boolean algebra) proofs. This can also be done, but can be less insightful. I like the more reasoning proofs.

Comment: Thank you! your explanation is very good. Although I like using boolean algebra proofs. It's easier for me at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, problems like this one are best approached on the logic level (by expanding the set theory definitions then using the laws of logic), and trying to find the structure that is available in the expressions.

Looking at the structure of both sides of
$$
\tag 0
(A - B) \cup (B - C) \;=\; (A \cup (B- C)) - (B \cap C)
$$
there is some kind of 'distribution' going on here, of the leftmost $\;\cup\;$ over the leftmost $\;-\;$.$
\newcommand{\calc}{\begin{align} \quad &}
\newcommand{\op}[1]{\\ #1 \quad & \quad \unicode{x201c}}
\newcommand{\hints}[1]{\mbox{#1} \\ \quad & \quad \phantom{\unicode{x201c}} }
\newcommand{\hint}[1]{\mbox{#1} \unicode{x201d} \\ \quad & }
\newcommand{\endcalc}{\end{align}}
\newcommand{\ref}[1]{\text{(#1)}}
\newcommand{\then}{\Rightarrow}
\newcommand{\followsfrom}{\Leftarrow}
\newcommand{\equiv}{\Leftrightarrow}
\newcommand{\true}{\text{true}}
\newcommand{\false}{\text{false}}
$ So we can try to find such a 'distribution law', by calculating the elements of $\;(A-B)\cup Z\;$:
$$\calc
    x \in (A - B) \cup Z
\op\equiv\hint{definitions of $\;\cup\;$ and $\;-\;$}
    (x \in A \land x \not\in B) \lor x \in Z
\op\equiv\hints{distribute $\;\lor\;$ over $\;\land\;$}
               \hint{-- since we're trying to find a distribution law}
    (x \in A \lor x \in Z) \land (x \not\in B \lor x \in Z)
\op\equiv\hint{RHS: DeMorgan -- to reach shape $\;P \land \lnot Q\;$}
    (x \in A \lor x \in Z) \land \lnot (x \in B \land x \not\in Z)
\op\equiv\hint{definitions of $\;\cup\;$ and of $\;-\;$ twice}
    x \in (A \cup Z) - (B - Z)
\endcalc$$
Therefore we're proven the law
$$
\tag 1
(A - B) \cup Z \;=\; (A \cup Z) - (B - Z)
$$
And substituting $\;Z := B-C\;$ in $\ref 1$ and combining this with $\ref 0$ leaves us to prove
$$
\tag 2
B - (B - C) \;=\; B \cap C
$$
which should be easy.

---

As another way to approach this, we could prove that the right hand side of $\ref 0$ is equal to $\;(A \cup B) - (B \cap C)\;$, perhaps using $\ref 2$, and then use the law
$$
\tag 3
(A - B) \cup (B - C) \;=\; (A \cup B) - (B \cap C)
$$
or its logic level equivalent
$$
\tag 4
(\lnot Q \land P) \lor (Q \land \lnot R) \;\equiv\; (\lnot Q \then P) \land (Q \then \lnot R)
$$
Both sides of $\ref 4$ can be read as "if $\;Q\;$ then $\;\lnot R\;$ else $\;P\;$".

---

That second approach shows us that the original $\ref 0$ is in a sense symmetrical around $\;B\;$, just like $\ref 3$ is, and like $\ref 4$ is around $\;Q\:$.  So this suggests a third approach for proving $\ref 0$: work on the logic level, and treat the cases $\;x \in B\;$ and $\;x \not\in B\;$ separately.

So first we 
$$\calc
    \tag 0 (A - B) \cup (B - C) \;=\; (A \cup (B- C)) - (B \cap C)
\op\equiv\hint{set extensionality; definitions of $\;\cup, -, \cap\;$}
    \langle \forall x ::
        (x \in A \land x \not\in B) \lor (x \in B \land x \not\in C) 
        \\ & \;\equiv\;
        (x \in A \lor (x \in B \land x \not\in C)) \land \lnot (x \in B \land x \in C)
    \rangle
\endcalc$$

In the case $\;x \in B\;$, we can simplify as follows:
$$\calc
    \langle \forall x ::
        (x \in A \land \false) \lor (\true \land x \not\in C) 
        \\ & \;\equiv\;
        (x \in A \lor (\true \land x \not\in C)) \land \lnot (\true \land x \in C)
    \rangle
\op\equiv\hint{logic: simplify}
    \langle \forall x ::
        x \not\in C
        \;\equiv\;
        (x \in A \lor x \not\in C) \land x \not\in C
    \rangle
\op\equiv\hint{logic: RHS simplifies to LHS}
    \true
\endcalc$$

In the case $\;x \not\in B\;$, we get:
$$\calc
    \langle \forall x ::
        (x \in A \land \true) \lor (\false \land x \not\in C) 
        \\ & \;\equiv\;
        (x \in A \lor (\false \land x \not\in C)) \land \lnot (\false \land x \in C)
    \rangle
\op\equiv\hint{logic: simplify}
    \langle \forall x ::
       x \in A 
        \;\equiv\;
        x \in A
    \rangle
\op\equiv\hint{logic}
    \true
\endcalc$$

---

Hopefully these three different approaches give a bit more insight.